# scala3: Methods on enum case, possible?

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types, gadt, scala-3

I'm trying to define an ADT (tagged union type, actually).

```scala
enum MyEnum{
  case MyFirstCase(value:String) extends MyEnum{
    def someMethod = "whatever"
  }

}
```

But the compiler complains... Is it possible to add methods specific cases of a Scala3 enum (GADT)?

Or do we have to rely with the usual `sealed trait` encoding?

Comment: How would you call the method?

Comment: @SwiftMangо `MyEnum.MyFirstCase("").someMethod` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with extension methods! See the example below.

The compiler will infer the enum type (here `MyEnum`) instead of the precise case type (here `MyEnum.A.type` in the example), so you need to specify it yourself in some cases.

```
enum MyEnum:
  case A

extension (a: MyEnum.A.type)
  def specificMethod() = println("ok")

MyEnum.A.specificMethod() // works

val preciseA: MyEnum.A.type = MyEnum.A
preciseA.specificMethod() // works

val unpreciseA = MyEnum.A // inferred type: MyEnum
unpreciseA.specificMethod() // compile error (specificMethod is not part of MyEnum)
```

Note that Scala 3 also provide union types in the following form, which may be easier to use in your case:

```
type MyUnion = A | B

// and then you can define A and B with the methods you want
class A:
  def specificToA()

class B:
  def specificToB()
```

Comment: with good old methods Is not possible then, right?

Comment: you're right: the Scala 3 syntax doesn't accept a "template body" for enum cases (https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/internals/syntax.html)